# Artifactory Plugin with Dockerized Declarative Pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory

I am trying to get dockerized build with Jenkins declarative pipeline. I am using the Artifactory plugin for resolving the dependencies. The below Pipeline works for `agent: any` but gives an authorization error for the dockerfile.

```
def server = Artifactory.server ARTIFACTORY_NAME
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
def buildInfo

pipeline {
    agent {
        dockerfile true
    }

    stages {
        stage('Artifactory configuration') {
            steps {
                script {
//                    rtMaven.tool = "maven 3.3.9"
                    rtMaven.deployer server: server
                    rtMaven.resolver server: server
                    buildInfo = Artifactory.newBuildInfo()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.MAVEN_HOME="/usr/share/maven"
                    env.JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
                    echo "MAVEN_HOME ${MAVEN_HOME}"
                    echo "JAVA_HOME ${JAVA_HOME}"
                    rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean install test', buildInfo: buildInfo
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The `JAVA_HOME` and `MAVEN_HOME` are set same as in the Dockerfile. The error is shown below:

```
 Non-resolvable parent POM for ARTIFACTORY: Could not transfer artifact ARTIFACTORY from/to artifactory (ARTIFACTORY_PATH): 
Not authorized , ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 11, column 13 -> [1m[Help 2][m
```

Comment: Does the maven build work without the artifactory plugin? you can use a tools section to define your maven/JDK

Comment: The build has dependencies to be downloaded from the artifactory so I can't completely build this pom without the plugin but dummy projects (without dependencies), seem to work. I also tried setting maven with rtMaven.tool = "maven 3.3.9" but it gives the same error.

Comment: I noticed that you did not define snapshot and release repositories on rtMaven.resolver. see https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Working+With+Pipeline+Jobs+in+Jenkins

Comment: I am downloading the artifacts directly from the repo and this works when used without the dockerfile. I think the issue could be because maven inside the docker doesn't see the settings.xml from the plugin.